# How to set Dialog result while clicking X - close window button in ControlsFX

Tags: java, dialog, javafx-2

I extended ControlsFX Dialog to create a custom ValidationDialog. I added some custom buttons where, one of them trigger a validation operation after clicking on it. If validation is passed, the dialog is closed with the OK result, but if dialog is not valid, a dummy Action objech is assigned to a dialog result action. It purpose (dumy result) is just to save information that user tried to fill dialog, and allow him to make some corrections (not to close window). Everything would be ok, but there is one scenario which creates wrong result. If user will fill form with an error data, than click validation button and after that he will click X button (close window). After those steps the dialog result will be still a validation button. I tried to bind some listener to window onCloseRequest() property, but it is not reacting. How to solve this issue?

Below is a shortened version of my code:

```
public class ValidationDialog extends Dialog {

    private ValidationDialog thisDialog;

    public final Action DUMMY_ACTION = new AbstractAction("OTHER") {
        {
            ButtonBar.setType(this, ButtonBar.ButtonType.OTHER);
        }

        @Override
        public void execute(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            //do nothing
        }
    };
    public final Action VALID_OK = new AbstractAction("OK"){
        {
            ButtonBar.setType(this, ButtonBar.ButtonType.OK_DONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void execute(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (isValid()) {
                thisDialog.setResult(this);
                thisDialog.hide();
            } else {
                thisDialog.setResult(DUMMY_ACTION);
            }
        }
    };


    public ValidationDialog(Object owner, String title) {
        super(owner, title);
        thisDialog = this;
    }

    private boolean isValid(){
        return false;
    }
}
```

and it's call:

```
ValidationDialog validationDialog = new ValidationDialog(stage, "Fill form");
Action result = validationDialog.show();
if (result.equals(validationDialog.VALID_OK)){
   //do important stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One would have expected that clicking X will always mean cancel.

So far the only way is to create own `boolean` variable like "valid" with getter, then set it before `hide()`.

outside do:

```
if (dlg.isValid()) {
    //dlg success
} else {
    //dlg fail
}
```